# Node properties not found while loading .ttl turtle file in networkx graph

Tags: python, rdf, networkx, rdflib

I parsed a turtle file in the rdf graph. This by using rdflib_to_networkx_multidigraph(), I converted it into networkx graph. When I export the networkx graph as graphML, everything is a node or edges, and there is no properties of node. If I search for attributes, it shows nothing.

```
from rdflib.extras.external_graph_libs import *
from rdflib import Graph, URIRef, Literal
import networkx as nx
from networkx.classes.function import info
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = Graph()
graph.parse("filename.ttl", format="turtle")
nx_graph = rdflib_to_networkx_multidigraph(graph)
nx.write_graphml(nx_graph,"example.graphml")
```

Comment: What do you expect as attribute of a node? RDF is made of triples `(s,p,o)` - those are converted to a graph by creating nodes for `s` and `o` and an edge between `s` and `o` labeled with `p`. So, what else do you expect? It is **not** a property graph ...